# RS232 from Linux SBC to Windows PC

Tags: serial-port, ubuntu-18.04

I have a RS232 device that is connected to a Linux SBC. I have Windows only software that is designed to communicate directly to that RS232 device.

Is there any software that exists to that I an install on my Linux SBC to allow it to just pass the RS232 communications directly from the RS232 device to my Windows computer?

Answer (score 0):

How your Windows PC is connected to the Linux SBC (serial, ethernet, etc.)?

Btw, you can try running Windows software on Linux machine via `wine`

Make sure your Linux user belongs to the group owning the serial port (usually the group is `dialout` or `tty`). Otherwise, you won't be able to communicate via the serial port.